# How to get all translation key in next-i18next

Tags: reactjs, next.js

### Question Summary

How do most users add the translation key to the json file when translating?
Manually...?

### What do I want

I'm trying to get all the translation keys used on all the pages.
Also, is it possible to get the untranslated translation keys automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use some extraction tools, for example https://github.com/i18next/i18next-parser or https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner?

Comment: Try it, and if it solved your question then mark the answer as accepted :) Or feel free to ask another questions if the solution does not work for you

Comment: I had tried those and doens't works like expected. next-scanner and next-parser didn't works for me either. They both doesn't get the text (in native language) and place that text with a a key in a json file. I mean, i guess the OP needs tool for text extraction in files that are translated yet.